# How to improve communication between microservices

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, microservices

In our company we use spring boot, microservices, spring cloud and so on... We are happy with this infrastructure, but I still have some concerns:
we use rest as comunication protocoll and even if a I find it great, I still think that we could find something better. With rest:

- you need to use a client and a server (restcontroller)
- you need to know the server `URI`, the http method (`POST, GET, PUT,...`)
- you need know where params go (body, querystring)
- ....

Don't you think It would be much easier if we had something like RMI? I know it's a quite old technology(and it's not language independent), but it made life easier (you just need an interface and its implementation).

Searching around, I found some interesting projects like feign clients or spring cloud stream, but none of them seem to be the silver bullet.

What do you think about this topic? Is that a problem that you feel? If so, how do you approach it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

In my company, we use JMS to add a "intern" communication stack to our microservice stack. It is reliable, simple to use, efficient and very performant.

We use [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) as implementation, but [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) is also widely used.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. We use rabbitMQ too and there is a very nice RPC implementation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#_message_correlation_with_a_reply_queue) but I was trying to understand if there is a better solution.

Have you seen this http://www.grpc.io/?

Comment: We do not use it as a RPC tools but as a message exchange (which is the main goal of JMS). RPC tools generally does not answer many questions JMS does : what happens if the network is temporarily down ? What if you want to address one instance ? All instances ? A specific class or type of instance ? With JMS it is really easy to address all those use case, i'm not sur you can easily do it with RPC tools. You can do RPC over JMS, but i think it may be easier to design the application as a message-driven application.

Comment: You can also have a look at [akka](http://akka.io/), wich is also a good tool to design message-driven application, and is widely used for this use case (internal microservices communication)

Answer (score 3):

Microservices are not meant to be tightly coupled , RMI requires your code on both end  , which was fun when you didnt control the other side eg clients who do not want to upgrade and it was a B!@*! to get through firewalls.

Soap solved most of those things you mention unfortunately Java never had a good Soap stack. That said Rest has other advantages especially when accessing the service from a web page and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Cloud Netflix and Eureka](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) as Service Discovery and [Client-Side Load Balancing with Ribbon](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka#client-side-load-balancing-with-ribbon).

With the help of those you can communicate between microservice by 'service names' instead of service locations.

Check out [this demo](https://bitbucket.org/ikryvorotenko/microservises-demo/). It should be VERY USEFULL for undestanding microservices communications.

Here we have 2 simple microservices and Discovery Service for communications between them.

Comment: yes we do use them. But with them case we solve the URI discovery issue (and balancing) We also use spring cloud config server for managing configuration. 
But I still think that write a rest client/server is quite expensive even with all these technologies on board. Is rest the best solution we have? Isn't there anything easier to use?